# What is the distribution function of a random outcome in closed interval [0,1]

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

a point is thrown  at random on the interval [0,1], and if the outcome is x, you get 100x dollars. Y represents the amount of money you get.

What is the pdf of X?
what is the pdf of Y?

I thought the answer of X is uniform distribution. and Y=100X.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Both of the distributions are uniform. The cdf of $X$ is given by
$$
F_X(x)=x
$$
for $0\le x\le1$ and the cdf of $Y$ is given by
$$
F_Y(y)=\Pr\{Y\le y\}=\Pr\{100X\le y\}=\Pr\biggl\{X\le\frac y{100}\biggr\}=F_X\Bigl(\frac y{100}\Bigr)=\frac y{100}
$$
for $0\le y\le 100$. Hence, the pdf of $X$ is $f_X(x)=1$ for $0\le x\le1$ and the pdf of $Y$ is $f_Y(y)=1/100$ for $0\le y\le 100$.